# Node can't see the file in a react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, file, find

I have a React project and I configured a build process in a file named build.js. The file tree is as below:

File structure:

[image]

I added "node build.js" script to scripts in package.json. It works fine on MacOS. However when I try to run the same `npm run build` script in my Windows machine, I get an error which says: "The system cannot find the file specified." "node build.js" command works fine when I move the file outside of project, for example to desktop. However, it does not work in the project.

The error from console:

[image]

I searched for any similar problem, but could not find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

edit: I solved my problem. It sees the file but can't see the file which should be removed by script. I misunderstood the problem and this is a false alarm. Sorry.

Comment: Can you share `build.js` and `package.json`?